# Continuing the code execution while concurrent.future keeps running pararell processes

Tags: python, concurrency, concurrent.futures

I'm new to concurrent.futures. I have been using it to run paralell calculations. Most typically I use:

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=self.cpu_cores) as executor:
      results = [executor.submit( some .py file) for task in task list]
```

followed by

```
for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results):


if __name__ == '__main__':
```

Is it possible to make the main python script continue with its tasks before the pararell processes finish?

In particular, can I, e.g., start a queue of 30 paralell tasks and then run a "while" loop which runs repeatedly until all these 30 tasks are finished?

I have got the idea how to do it if I just added the most external task to the task list for pararell processes, however I have some objects that I need to keep up, so I'd rather if it was one main .py file that runs itself and some pararell .py.

I can't find proper tutorials for that and I don't even know if it is possible to make the main code carry on executing its code before concurrent processes finish.